# what is Readline backward-delete-char (Rubout)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, readline

`man bash` says:

> backward-delete-char (Rubout)
>
> Delete the character behind the cursor.  When given a numeric argument, save the deleted text on the kill ring.

Is Rubout just Delete key on keyboard? Because it has the same function as bash describes backward-delete-char.

But when I try:

> backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout)
>
> Kill backward to the beginning of the line.

Consider following case:

```
$ testa testb testc testd
```

assume the point is on `testc`'s t, now I press Control+x then press Delete key on keyboard. The result is:

```
$ testa testb [3~testc testd
```

I just can't understand it, am I missing something?

Comment: <kbd>Rubout</kbd> is not <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, it is <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three concepts to be clarified in the simple description of:

> backward-delete-char (Rubout)

- Keys
  There is a key called <kbd>Delete</kbd>, one which you are using in your examples.
  That key erase "the next character".
  If the line contains `test1` and the cursor (the blinking indicator) is over the letter `s`, <kbd>Delete</kbd> will erase the `s`.
  In contrast, there is a key called <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, which, in exactly the same conditions will erase the letter `e`. That is the letter which *precede* the cursor.

  That <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key is being described by "backward-delete-char (Rubout)" in the bash manual.

  That key, obviously "Delete the character behind the cursor".
- Numeric Argument
  To give it a "numeric argument" you need to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>, for example, which will place a `2` as an argument to the next command (or key).

  Again, if the word test is written in the line, and the cursor is at the `s`, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> and then the <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. That will *Back* erase two characters, the `te` in the word `test`.
- The kill ring.
  When something is erased, in most cases, is placed in a kill ring.
  To get what is inside the "kill ring" use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>.

  If you erase several characters, with <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, those characters will reapear using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>.

  In Detail:

  If you use an argument to the command <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, you will erase as many characters as the argument say "before" the current position of the cursor.

  If there is this string at the command prompt:

  ```
  $ testa testb testc
  ```

  And the cursor is under the letter "b", an <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> will remove the characters "est":

  ```
  $ testa tb testc
  ```

  Those characters will be printed back with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>

Now, the:

> backward-kill-line (C-x Rubout)

Means to press: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Which will place the whole line "before the cursor" in the kill ring.

And, the keys: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Delete</kbd> have no action defined for them, which will make the equivalent ANSI code to be printed:

```
[3~
```

In your terminal. That could be changed in the ~/.inputrc for the readline library which bash use. But that is outside the scope for this answer, I believe.